# How to make "http://" or "https://" optional in HTML URL validation

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, validation

HTML's URL validation expects `http://` or `https://` by default. I tried adding a pattern attribute with custom regular expression along with `type="url"`, but failed to do so successfully.

Is there any option that we can override the regular expression to make  `http://` or `https://` optional?

Comment: It may be helpful in the future if you learn the regular expression syntax so these types of modifications are easy: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Can you not use `[Url]`

Comment: Simply, something like `/some/path` is *not* a URL, so an input of `type="url"` won't accept it. You'll have to use something like `type="text"` along with the `pattern` attribute to validate via regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried the code I posted below?

Comment: Why did some one down voted this question? I too gone through some comments like- setting type="url" for an html input has http:// or https:// optional by default. But this is not true, for me i checked in IE11 and chrome (thought it might be browser specific) and found http:// or htts:// is a mandatory prefix. But www was found optional.

Comment: @Murat Yildiz, I followed Chris Pratt's opinion by making the type="text" and set a pattern ((http(s)?://)?([\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}) and that worked for me. Thanks Chris.

Comment: I thought you need a "regular expression to make http:// or https:// optional". Anyway, I voted up ChrisPratt's answer as well.

Comment: @Murat Yildiz, Appreciate your help. I have already voted for his comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this regular expression that validates URLs without *"http://", "https://" or "www"*:

```
//Validates url without "http://", "https://" or "www"
[RegularExpression(@"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file|)+\:\/\/)?[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])", ErrorMessage = "Please check the url")]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use "DataAnnotationsExtensions" library ([MVC 4 URL validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249105/mvc4-url-validation)). But it's too old, I don't know how it works with latest MVC versions.

2. My solution. Not validation in model, show URL as hyperlink:

   Model:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string WebSite { get; set; }
    }
   ```

   View:

   ```
   @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WebSite)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WebSite)</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr> 
   }
   ```